# I'm stuck, what is the answer to this riddle?

Tags: riddle, lateral-thinking, rhyme

I've heard this rhyming riddle recently, and I just can't work it out. What am I thinking of?

---

My first is in cow, but not in pat.
My second in mouse, yet not in rat.
My third is in rhythm, but not in rhyme.
My whole is a waste of all your time.

---

**Clue:** This has now been answered, but here's a clue, in case you're struggling...

> The answer is hiding in plain sight.

Comment: Logician's answer is exactly how I would have approached it, but it still doesn't make much sense. Are you sure you didn't mishear some of it?

Comment: There was a little fib there, I wasn't sure how to introduce a riddle so I told a tale of being told the riddle. I wrote this, and I'm sure it's all there.

Comment: Ah, thanks. Others have done that before, so I should have realized :)

Comment: It could, perhaps, have gone without that pre-amble, I might just go right into the contents in future.

Comment: I'd suggest changing the title to be a bit more relevant (I don't actually have any specific ideas, unfortunately), as the title gives no real information about the puzzle itself.

Comment: The title has been modified since I wrote it, it initially said "what is this?"... Not that that's a clue or anything...

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because there is no answer.

Comment: But there is an answer, it's clearly defined. Check the reply by @Prinsig

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This might be a bit out there but, perhaps...

> ...there is no answer. The last line says "My whole is a waste of all your time." What if it refers the the riddle as a whole? There's no solution, therefore it's a waste of your time.

On the flip side, this may not be the case given the use of the word

> "all". It's not a waste of all your time, just some of it.

Comment: That's it! :-) Just FYI I felt that the word 'all' in that context helped the little poem to scan (basically it sounds better, to me).

Comment: wow, i feel like i accomplished something! i found a fitting answer to an unanswerable riddle!

Comment: @JLee I was sure this wasn't correct, we both feel like that!

Answer (score 15):

Is it perhaps

> waste of time?

Going through each of the clues, one possible combination of letters would be

> 'WOT'. The clues could be referring to the first letters of each word - for example, "my second" indicating what letter the second word starts with.

In this way, the letters

> 'WOT' stand for something that is a waste of all your time - and you can't get much more exact than "waste of time".

Comment: I choose this as the correct answer, in my mind.

Answer (score 5):

Initial thoughts/partial answer:

It looks like each 'part' describes a letter that appears in the first word but not the second.

This doesn't help us much until 'rhythm/rhyme':

> the letter 't' is the only one that appears only in rhythm, so the third letter of the solution is **t**

The words that appear with that information are:

> cut, wet, cot, out

The last line

> gives us the definition of the solution. Not sure yet whether the whole thing is only 3 letters long or if we need to use the first three letters at the start of a word - if the latter, the first three don't necessarily need to form a word themselves

Comment: what about the e in rhyme?

Comment: @kl78 'but *not* in rhyme' - we only want the letters that appear in rhythm

Comment: @LogicianWithAHat there is also a second "h" you dropped. It might be possible that the 3rd line actually gives you "th".

Comment: @Avigrail It's possible - I was working under the assumption that any number of 'h's would be ruled out by dint of there being one in 'rhyme'

Answer (score 5):

Maybe it is

> **coot**
> Take the "co" from cow, the "o" from mouse, and the "t" from rhythm.
> Google says coot, informally, means "a foolish or eccentric person, typically an old man," so it's no stretch to say that a foolish person could be "a waste of all your time."
> <sub>However, I was hoping that the answer involved taking the "th" from rhythm, as Avigrail pointed out in his comment.</sub>

Answer (score 3):

I think the answer is literally

> Cut Somehow

Why

My first is in cow, but not in pat.

> Taking the whole COW

My second in mouse, yet not in rat.

> and a MOUSE

My third is in rhythm, but not in rhyme.

> and TH

My whole is a waste of all your time.

> Mixing it all together gives COWMOUSETH

of all the different ones selected this...

> means the riddle is CUT SOMEHOW and therefore waste of time.